# Write regex to remove space before st,nd,rd or th from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string 
Original string

```
"1 st-May-2014"                
"2 nd-May-2014"                 
"3 rd-May-2014"                 
"14 th-May-2014"
```

**Output should be**

```
"1st-May-2014"  
"2nd-May-2014"
"3rd-May-2014"
"14th-May-2014"
```

Now i wanted to remove space before **st,nd,rd and th** from the above string using RegEx in JavaScript.

Comment: It take it `replace(' ', '')` isn't enough?

Comment: What's stopping you? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```
result = subject.replace(/\s+(?=(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b)/g, "");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\s+              # Match whitespace
(?=              # if the following text can be matched after it:
 (?:st|nd|rd|th) # one of the four "words"
 \b              # that end there (so as not to match "4 stones")
)                # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: Prompt answer with accepted solution! my vote +1

Comment: @imdadhusen, consider looking at my answer

Comment: How do you provide that explanation Tim? Any website?

Comment: Excellent!!! perfect explanation to understand it's logic

Comment: @AmitJoki: No, all hand-written :)

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need this:

```
result = subject.replace(/^(\d+)\s+(.*)$/gm,"$1$2");
```